# in batch to write paragraph do must write echo 5 times?

Tags: batch-file

1.In batch to write paragraph must write echo 5 times like or can do it 1 time? echo (paragraph)
 2.I am new here I enjoy & it is helpful thanks all

Comment: It would be helpful to have a few more details. What is the code for your batch script?

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you are trying to do but I am not certain

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
:: Set end of line
for /f %%A in ('copy /Z "%~dpf0" nul') do set EOL=%%A^


:: Two empty lines are neccessary

echo This is line 1.!EOL!This is line 2.!EOL!This is line 3.

pause
```

And here is the output.

```
This is line 1.
This is line 2.
This is line 3.
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Comment: wow thats what I was looking to do Squashman thank you I will play with it

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this:

```
@echo off

set x=first line;second line
echo %x:;=&echo %
```